# commandbars("list range popup") not working in macos excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add button on cell rightclick. I am able to achieve it using below code. But when i have some content in the sheet as table its not working in those cells. apart from those cells in the table its working in rest of the cells in the sheet.

```
Set TableCellMenu = Application.CommandBars("cell").Controls.Add(Temporary:=True, before:=1, Type:=msoControlButton)   
With TableCellMenu
    .Caption = "MyButton"            
    .FaceId = 755                                       
    .OnAction = "Writeback"         
End With
```

After my research got to know that there are two types of context menus. The one i am looking for is "List range popup".

whenever I am trying below code, its not working.

```
Set TableCellMenu = Application.CommandBars("list range popup").Controls.Add(Temporary:=True, before:=1, Type:=msoControlButton)   
With TableCellMenu
 .Caption = "MyButton"            
 .FaceId = 755                                       
 .OnAction = "Writeback"         
End With
```

I tried few other approaches suggested in the internet and changing the string to camel case but still no luck.

Update:

Answer by Taller helped me solve this issue.

Comment: The code works well with Excel 365.

Comment: Yes @taller_ExcelHome, it works well if the cell is normal cell but when I import csv and then if i rightclick on the content cell its not showing the option.

Comment: Do you import csv with Power Query?

Comment: We import using below code.       

`With Worksheets(outSheet).QueryTables.Add(Connection:=connectionName, destination:=Worksheets(outSheet).Cells(startRow, startColumn))`

Comment: I have post the solution. Please test it.

Comment: @taller_ExcelHome your solution worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Excel `context menu` is a popup menu that becomes visible when you right-click on a cell, chart, or any other object within your worksheet. It is important to locate the correct menu if you aim to customize the controls on the context menu.

`list range popup` is the context menu for a `table` (This name can be confusing, Insert > Table). Importing a CSV file using `QueryTables` will create a query table. You could customize its context menu as below.

```
Set TableCellMenu = Application.CommandBars("query").Controls. _
        Add(Temporary:=True, before:=1, Type:=msoControlButton)
With TableCellMenu
    .Caption = "MyButton"
    .FaceId = 755
    .OnAction = "Writeback"
End With
```

Comment: Thanks Taller_ExcelHome. This worked. 

Is there similar option to change `Application.ShortcutMenus(xlWorksheetCell)` from cell type to query type?

I am using Menu type in other method and its behaving same. Once I import CSV the menu is not working.

Comment: There are few types of shortcutMenus in excel. This menu popus up on right click. For example we have Cell which i mentione above and another example is `Application.ShortcutMenus(xlColumnHeader)` in which menu item will be added to menu when you right click on cell header.

Comment: This is for column header menu : `Application.ShortcutMenus(xlColumnHeader).MenuItems.AddMenu("MyHeaderMenu", 1)`. This is for cell right click menu: `Application.ShortcutMenus(xlWorksheetCell).MenuItems.AddMenu("MyCellMenu", 1)`

Comment: It isn't documented on MS online doc. I'm not sure how to get the const for `query type`.

Comment: ok no problem. Thanks for your help.